# Storing Arrays in DB gives PHP Notice Undefined Offset 1

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays

Getting an array from Android Client. Storing it in the DB gives a `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\filepath\ on line 67`

I am trying to achieve this in my DB:

```
User_Id  | Book_Id
---------|---------
3        | 120
---------|---------
1        | 17
---------|---------
```

`php` file that collects the post from **android client**:

```
if(isset($_POST['watch'])){
           $jsonwatch = $_POST['watch'];
           $array = json_decode($jsonwatch, true);
           $response["error"] =! ($db_watch->storeClass($array['attendees'], $array['lesson_iDs']));

}
```

`php` file that is called in the **notice**:

```
public function storeClass($attendees, $lesson_iDs) {
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO watch (date, user_id, lesson_id) VALUES(NOW(), ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $attendees, $lesson_id);

foreach ($attendees as $index => $attendee) {
    $lesson_id = $lesson_iDs[$index]; // Line 67
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if(!$result){
        echo '\n';
        printf("Error for attendee %d in lesson %d : %s.\n", $attendee, $lesson_id, $stmt->error);
        echo '\n';
        echo '\n';
    }
}

$stmt->close();

// result
return $result;
}
```

**UPDATE!**

`var_dump($array):`

```
C:\wamp64\www\ghanaweb\AddClass.php:19:
array (size=4)
'attendees' => 
array (size=2)
0 => string '5a6611e89e9e26.27646060' (length=23)
  1 => string '5a4cfae69fd7b6.01373362' (length=23)
 'id' => int 0
'lesson_iDs' => 
array (size=1)
  0 => int 4
'lesson_id' => int 0
 {"error":false}
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `var_dump($array)` in the collection bit?

Comment: `var_dump($jsonwatch): {&quot;73327&quot;,&quot;883992&quot;],&quot;id&quot;:0,&quot;lesson_iDs&quot;:[1],&quot;lesson_id&quot;:0}` the random numbers _73327_ and _883992_ are the User_IDs

Comment: Unsure how you got from `var_dump($array)` to `var_dump($jsonwatch)`...

Comment: My bad @JonStirling I will add the entire output of `var_dump($array)` at the end of the question

Comment: I dnt know what are you trying to do. But make sure the array index exists. Use : if(isset(lesson_iDs[$index])) { //do_your_stuff }

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use the $ index as the ID in your case and it's only the number of the masive and nothing more
Try to use

```
$lesson_id = $lesson_iDs[$attendee['lesson_id']];
```

Comment: I got `Warning: Illegal string offset 'lesson_id' `

Answer (score 0):

$lesson_iDs  array has only one element and in the for loop you are trying to access a second element which is not existing